# Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' Tomcat 8 & Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, jdbc

Using tomcat 8 with Eclipse  Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' ::: I have added mysql connecter every where and I still can't connect.

```
WEB-INF/lib/
Java Resources/Libraries/
tomcat/lib/  // however I don't see the jar file in my project
```

[image]

[image]

web.xml

[image]

Tomcat Context.xml

[image]

Comment: The "Library" named "Apache Tomcat v8.0" is an Eclipse definition, not a live scan of the Tomcat `lib` folder. If you add a new .jar file to the folder, you need to update that definition in the Eclipse Preferences.

Comment: Thanks, but I am new to Eclipse, how do I update the definition?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add the mysql jar in classpath of Run Configurations.

[image: Run Configuration]

To do this choose menu Run > Run Configuration > Select your Tomcat Installation and the classpath tab. Click on button Add External JARs...

Answer (score 6):

Another thing you can try that worked for me is to add the mysql connector jar directly to the folder. Of course change to your environment.

C:[YOUR PATH]\apache-tomcat-8.5.24\lib

mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar

Comment: This was my issue, whoever set up the environments forgot to add this jar to the staging server.  Thanks from 2020

Answer (score 1):

Give Right click on project

1. go to properties
2. click on java build path
3. take add external jars
4. choose mysql connector from zip file
5. at last click apply and ok .

Answer (score 0):

In my case I fixed this issue as it was happening with tomcat7 7.0.56 on debian 8.11 and apparently this tomcat7 version has some beef with this debian.
When I downgraded to tomcat7 7.0.28 this error got fixed since jar was everywhere and only tomcat7 could have been the reason for not getting loaded.
I hope this helps someone else save the time that I lost debugging this one

Answer (score 0):

This comment is posted up and is fine but between steaps 2 and 3 you have to do step 2.50. You just forgot to import jar files into project path.

Give Right click on project

1. go to `properties`
2. click on java build path
   **2.50** In the right under Java Build Patch click`Library`
3. take add external jars
4. choose `mysql connector` from zip file
5. at last click apply and ok.